# Spring Framework Mapping / Handling "Did not find handler method"

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, web-applications

I am getting very frustrated.
I am trying to have static resources on my web application (css, js, etc). I prefer to have it in it's own servlet in a pretty and acceptable way but at this point I dont care how it looks as long as it works. I have tried many different ways but I am back to trying to use a resource mapping in the todo-servlet.xml and have been trying to access the resources this way. I will include some code. Any help would be great.

Error

```
...
Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: FF8AF3382877259D176ED83243961B8A; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/angular_full_version/css/style.css'; against '/login'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/angular_full_version/css/style.css'; against '/*todo*/**'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,029 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/angular_full_version/css/style.css'; against '/*admin*/**'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Checking match of request : '/angular_full_version/css/style.css'; against '/*user*/**'
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Public object - authentication not attempted
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Matching patterns for request [/Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css] are [/Angular_Full_Version/**]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - URI Template variables for request [/Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css] are {}
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Matching patterns for request [/Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css] are [/Angular_Full_Version/**]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapping [/Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/style]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@76de0cc1]]] and 1 interceptor
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - URI Template variables for request [/Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css] are {}
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css] is: -1
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapping [/Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/style]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@76de0cc1]]] and 1 interceptor
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css] is: -1
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Matching patterns for request [/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css] are [/Angular_Full_Version/**]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - URI Template variables for request [/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css] are {}
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapping [/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/style]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@76de0cc1]]] and 1 interceptor
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css] is: -1
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,030 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Matching patterns for request [/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css] are [/Angular_Full_Version/**]
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - URI Template variables for request [/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css] are {}
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapping [/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/style]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@76de0cc1]]] and 1 interceptor
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Last-Modified value for [/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css] is: -1
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
        DEBUG   2017-08-05 04:48:30,031 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    <code>
```

Tree
[image: https://gyazo.com/f4ea1bb67f97fafe8c6c076803e2d137]

header.jspf

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>QCC Greenhouse</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <!-- Page title set in pageTitle directive -->
    <title page-title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main Inspinia CSS files -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/css/animate.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="loadBefore" href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/css/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
```

navigation.jspf

```
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="">
        <a href="http://www.in28minutes.com" class="navbar-brand">in28Minutes</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/list-todos">Todos</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

index.jsp

```
    <%@ include file="../common/header.jspf"%>
<%@ include file="../common/navigation.jspf"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!-- ControllerAs syntax -->
<!-- Main controller with serveral data used in Inspinia theme on diferent view -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" class="{{$state.current.data.specialClass}}" landing-scrollspy id="page-top">

<!-- Main view  -->
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>

<!-- MetsiMenu -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"/>"></script>

<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"/>"></script>

<!-- Peace JS -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"/>"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/inspinia.js"/>"></script>

<!-- Main Angular scripts-->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/angular/angular.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/angular/angular-sanitize.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/angular-idle/angular-idle.js"/>"></script>

<!--
 You need to include this script on any page that has a Google Map.
 When using Google Maps on your own site you MUST signup for your own API key at:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
 After your sign up replace the key in the URL below..
-->
<script type="text/javascript" href="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQTpXj82d8UpCi97wzo_nKXL7nYrd4G70"/>"></script>

<!-- Anglar App Script -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/app.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/config.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/translations.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/directives.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/controllers.js"/>"></script>


<%@ include file="../common/footer.jspf"%>
```

footer.jspf

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>

<!-- MetsiMenu -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"/>"></script>

<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"/>"></script>

<!-- Peace JS -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"/>"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/inspinia.js"/>"></script>

<!-- Main Angular scripts-->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/angular/angular.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/angular/angular-sanitize.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.min.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/plugins/angular-idle/angular-idle.js"/>"></script>

<!--
 You need to include this script on any page that has a Google Map.
 When using Google Maps on your own site you MUST signup for your own API key at:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
 After your sign up replace the key in the URL below..
-->
<script type="text/javascript" href="<c:url value="/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQTpXj82d8UpCi97wzo_nKXL7nYrd4G70"/>"></script>
<!-- Anglar App Script -->
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/app.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/config.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/translations.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/directives.js"/>"></script>
<script href="<c:url value="/Angular_Full_Version/js/controllers.js"/>"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

todo-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.craftinggamertom" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="language" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/Angular_Full_Version/**" location="/style" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/Angular_Full_Version/css/**" location="/style" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/Angular_Full_Version/js/**" location="/style" />


</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>To do List</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

   <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping> 

    <error-page>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Comment: We can't see any folder named `/Angular_Full_Version` in your folder structure

Comment: Thank you @sunkuet02 I updated the tree

Comment: If my solution worked for you, You can Accept my answer. So that, community can easily be benefited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If you really need `style` in folder structure then you can do the followings:

- Remove all the `<mvc:resources />` tags and the below tag:

  ```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/style/**" location="/style/" />
  ```
- Then add `/style` to all the link as like:

  ```
  <script href="<c:url value="/style/Angular_Full_Version/js/app.js"/>"></script>
  ```

**Solution 2**

You can delete the `style` folder add one step up `Angular_Full_Version` folder. (This is my suggestion as I have seen that you are focusing on `Angular_Full_Version` folder. To follow this :

- Copy the `Angular_Full_Version` folder and paste it under `webapp` folder and delete the `style` folder.
- Remove all the `<mvc:resources />` tags and the below tag:

  ```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/Angular_Full_Version/**" location="/Angular_Full_Version/" />
  ```

**Best Practice(I have found in different blogs)**

- There should be a folder named `resources` under the `WEB-INF` folder. And under `resources` folder all the resources like `images`, `js`, `css` contains.
- Then the `mvc:resources` be like :

  ```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
  ```
- And while using :

  ```
  <script href="<c:url value="/resources/js/app.js"/>"></script>
  ```

Comment: This is helpful. I decided to use static non-js content when testing and your suggestion worked. No the problem is, I went back to using Angular JS and it cannot find the js files for an unknown reason. The "src" tag seems to be the only difference `<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controllers.js"/>"></script>` from the link tag that currently works for my css files `<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">`